# Why isn't my 'addDay' function updating the date in my browser using client scripts?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testing, testcafe

Created a function in testcafe automation "addDay", to change the day to check streaks in browser for that day.

```
export async function addDay(NoOfDays: number) {
    const CalculatedDays = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (NoOfDays * 24*60*60*1000)).valueOf();
     // console.log(CalculatedDays);
    const incrementaldate = {
      clientScripts: [
        { module: "mockdate" },
        { content: `window.MockDate.set(${CalculatedDays})` }
      ]

    };

           console.log(incrementaldate);
       return incrementaldate;

  }
```

The function is returning incremental date correctly like below but its not setting the the date in browser

```
{
  clientScripts: [
    { module: 'mockdate' },
    { content: 'window.MockDate.set(1685098891700)' }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting the day change & then streak will be visible for that day but its not

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you please create a complete example that can be run locally without any additional setup (see [how to create a minimal working example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) article)?

Comment: @mlosev created an issue here- https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7725.It might help.